# Format a LWC column created with lightning-datatable

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to format this column:

```
columns = [
    { label: 'Case Number', fieldName: 'CaseNumber', sortable: true, hideDefaultActions: true },
    { label: 'Case Title', fieldName: 'Request_Title__c', sortable: true, hideDefaultActions: true  },
    { label: 'Task Category', fieldName: 'Task_Category__c', sortable: true, hideDefaultActions: true  },
    { label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status', sortable: true, hideDefaultActions: true  },
    { label: 'Record Type', fieldName: 'RecordTypeDeveloperName__c', sortable: true, hideDefaultActions: true  }
  ];
```

Where the value of RecordTypeDeveloperName__c has _ between names, and I want to change this to blank between names, I had tried to use the property "cellAttributes" with CSS but didn't work.

I appreciate the help from now.

Comment: you mean the value you get from RecordTypeDeveloperName__c, is something like; "Test_User_One", "Test_User_Two" and you want it do be "Test User One", "Test User Two", in you datatable?

Comment: Hi prem22, that's right

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, is to modify the data that you are receiving.

Example code taken from [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example)
For an example:
Let's say your data is in the following structure:

```
[{"name":"Name (0)","username":"Test_User_One","amount":39,"phone":"1652202867","closeAt":"2023-07-23T12:11:19.717Z"},{"name":"Name (1)","username":"Test_User_One","amount":57,"phone":"7441952227","closeAt":"2023-07-30T12:11:19.717Z"},{"name":"Name (2)","username":"Test_User_One","amount":1,"phone":"3601109302","closeAt":"2023-07-23T12:11:19.717Z"},{"name":"Name (3)","username":"Test_User_One","amount":50,"phone":"9656367124","closeAt":"2023-08-01T12:11:19.717Z"}]
```

As you can see it's an array of objects and we wish to see the data displayed for **username** to be **Test User One** instead of **Test_User_One**.

We can use [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

JS

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

const columns = [
    { label: 'Label', fieldName: 'name' },
    { label: 'UserName', fieldName: 'newUsername'}, // this is what I changed
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone' },
    { label: 'Balance', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'currency' },
    { label: 'CloseAt', fieldName: 'closeAt', type: 'date' },
];

export default class BasicDatatable extends LightningElement {
    data = [{"name":"Name (0)","username":"Test_User_One","amount":39,"phone":"1652202867","closeAt":"2023-07-23T12:11:19.717Z"},{"name":"Name (1)","username":"Test_User_One","amount":57,"phone":"7441952227","closeAt":"2023-07-30T12:11:19.717Z"},{"name":"Name (2)","username":"Test_User_One","amount":1,"phone":"3601109302","closeAt":"2023-07-23T12:11:19.717Z"},{"name":"Name (3)","username":"Test_User_One","amount":50,"phone":"9656367124","closeAt":"2023-08-01T12:11:19.717Z"}];
    columns = columns;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.data.forEach(item => {
            item.newUsername = item.username.replaceAll("_", " "); // creating a new property in data object.
        })
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<template>
    <div style="height: 300px;">
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
</template>
```

When we do this, in the end the, data will display something like this:
[image]

Okay, so the above is just an example, but however you are mutating the original field value from the data, so in this case, you wish to do something with the selected rows, then you know the data would not match with the one in production/sandbox as the data is mutated.

So one way to solve this is, create a new property in each object, basically just to display. (In this example, I create a new property called **newUsername**, and replace all "_" with " " just for display purpose)
So if I did something like this in my JS instead, only changes made are added below:

JS

```
const columns = [
    { label: 'Label', fieldName: 'name' },
    { label: 'UserName', fieldName: 'newUsername'}, // this is what I changed
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone' },
    { label: 'Balance', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'currency' },
    { label: 'CloseAt', fieldName: 'closeAt', type: 'date' },
];
this.data.forEach(item => {
            item.newUsername = item.username.replaceAll("_", " "); // creating a new property in data object.
        })
```

I will get the following data back

```
[{"name":"Name (0)","username":"Test_User_One","amount":20,"phone":"3740826763","closeAt":"2023-07-15T12:19:02.196Z","newUsername":"Test User One"},{"name":"Name (1)","username":"Test_User_One","amount":44,"phone":"1646118692","closeAt":"2023-07-20T12:19:02.196Z","newUsername":"Test User One"},
```

So you can see now for my columns I could change the fieldName to newUsername.

The advantage of doing it this way, is that let's say user selects one row, and you want to take all of the information and do something with the values. So in this case, you can still user username property from each object which will contain the actual value of the field, which is (**Test_User_One**), and use **newUsername** (**Test User One**) just to display.

I hope it helps! :)

Special thanks to [THIS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) website, as it is easy to change the js and html for testing purposes